# Where is the asp.net identity 2.2.1 Source code?

Tags: asp.net-identity

Where is the asp.net identity 2.2.1 Source code? I have found 2.1 here: https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com, and vNext here: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity but I am using 2.2.1 and need the source for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>At the moment when I look on this https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Readme.markdown the check-in tag says `v2.2.1`. This is the latest code for 2.* version.</s>

Codeplex have now closed. Source code for Identity v2 now been moved to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity

Comment: I guess that's it. It seemed like my class signatures were different in the dll from Nuget...